# Subexponental function for perfect graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I'm looking for a subexponental function so that every perfect graph contains a $K_{n}$ or a $\overline K _{n}$ subgraph.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Can you show your _attempts_ or _ideas_ for to solve this problem?

Comment: I know that every large enough graph G contains either $K_{n}$ or $\overline K_{n}$ as an induced subgraph. But how do I apply this theorem for every perfect graph and find a function?

Comment: In short, you are asking about Ramsey numbers, of which the 5th is not known.

Comment: @IvanNeretin the question is only looking for a very coarse bound for a specific class of graphs. It's possible the difficulty of the general Ramsey problem is not all that relevant here.

Comment: The following link shows a very much subexponential bound for perfect graphs: https://pimvanthof.github.io/COCOON2012_talk2.pdf

Answer (score 2):

It's not *exactly* the best bound possible, but it's roughly close: we claim that $f(n) = n^2$ will suffice.

First a hint if you want to try prove this bound yourself:

> In a proper colouring of a graph, every color class is an independent set (i.e., all the vertices with the same color form an induced $\overline{K_n}$).

And here's a full proof:

> Let $G$ be a perfect graph of order at least $n^2$. If it contains $K_n$, we are done. So assume it does not contain a $K_n$. Then the clique number $\omega(G) < n$. Since $G$ is perfect, $\omega(G) = \chi(G)$, so $G$ has a proper colouring $c$ with at most $n-1$ colours. Let $S$ be the biggest color class of the coloring $c$ (so all vertices in $S$ get the same color), and note that $|S| \geq \frac{n^2}{n-1} > n$ by the pigeonhole principle. Thus $S$ is an independent set of $G$ with at least $n$ vertices (i.e., $S$ contains an induced $\overline{K_n}$), and we are done.